# SSRS 2005 - Capturing RAISERROR message

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, error-handling

I am checking whether a user has a permission to view the report through dataset stored procedure and if the user doesn't, raiserror is called.

Is there a way to display a different message from SQL Server Reports 2005 when a stored procedure (that populates report dataset) raises error (through RAISERROR) instead of returning data?

Here is a skeleton code of dataset stored procedure

```
create procedure ReportSprocName
    @ClientID   int,
    @Login      sysname
as
begin
    --; check user's permission through @Login
    --; * Pseudo code *
    if @Login does not have permission begin
        raiserror(@Login does not have permission, 127, 1)
        return
    end

    select  id, name, etc...
    from    someTable   
end
GO
```

I am interested in two possibly solutions

1. Displaying error message within RAISERROR
2. Displaying a hardcoded custom message in SSRS report itself

Currently this is the default message displayed by SSRS reports
[image]

Comment: I have found a work-around but I am still eager to know how to capture RAISERROR message from SQL Server Report.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you allow the user fire to the report if they don't have permission to view it?

To display a custom message in the SSRS report itself:

1. Add a text field
2. Customize the text displayed on it to your satisfaction
3. Provide an expression for the Visibility > Hidden value (Properties Window).  IE:

   = iif( count(Fields!Application_Number.Value, "YOUR-DATASOURCE-NAME") > 0, true, false)

Comment: @rexem: "Why would you allow the user fire to the report if they don't have permission to view it" That's a valid question.  I have asked the developer who has created the menu but there is no way to associate a permission for the menu item "for now" but I still need to get something done and that is why I am looking for a "work-around" to get something done for now.

Comment: I haven't had to capture RAISERROR output in a report, sorry.

Comment: You might try defining a resultset in the RETURN clause you have in your example, but I imagine the columns needs to match what the report would produce when successfully run.

Comment: Or you could add a column to your stored procedure to populate with the value of the permission check - this would enable you to trigger the custom message.  Not all columns in the resultset need to be displayed to the user.

Comment: @rexem: What I did was that, I have added another datasource simply that returns a value whether a user has permission or not.  And instead of adding a new text field, I added a new expression on "NoRows" property of a table. --> =iif(First(Fields!HasPermission.Value, "permissionDataSet") = 0, "You do not have permission to view this report", "There are no certified labels generated for this client")  

               I have not marked your answer as answer but voted up because I am still interested in capturing RAISERROR value from SQL Server reports.  Thanks rexem for your suggestion.

Comment: Sung: No worries, I'm curious too.